# How to remove scripts (in a framework) when the ios app is archived?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm working on a cocoa pod framework which has a couple of shell scripts in it. After installing the pod, the user should add the following in app's build phase -> run script :

“${PODS_ROOT}/MyPod/MyPod/framework/MyPod.framework/scripts/build.sh”

After this the build works fine and app runs. But archiving creates problems. XCode gives an error saying:

```
iTunes Store Operation Failed
Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The file at path [SampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyPod.framework/scripts/build.sh] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
```

I've two concerns now:

1. Xcode doens't allow scripts to be a part of archive?
2. If thats the case, then how do I remove these scripts from archive? Is there a build setting like ${ARCHIVE_DIR} from where I can search for the latest archive and then remove the script. Or, is there some build setting where I can mention what files to ignore while building or archiving?

Also, I've already tried adding these files to 'exclude source file names' to the app's build settings. It didn't work since the script to be executed isn't a part of the app, but part of the framework integrated in app.

Also, my framework is a fat framework generated by using lipo on simulator build and device build. Which means that framework won't be code signed.

Comment: framework does not allow simulation code inside when push to store, is your framework use the script to combine simulation and device arch?

Comment: Yes, my framework is a universal framework which has device and simulator architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow simulation code inside framework when push to store, to overcome this, either ship the framework without simulator arch, or use external script to remove it during app build.

Example script can be found in some framework like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation), basically you have to add the script file in your framework, and tell user/dev to call this on their build script (it's the `strip-frameworks.sh`)

This issue is stated in this [archiving universal framework bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216)

Comment: I'm already doing that. But the problem is my equivalent of strip-frameworks.sh file should also be removed from built product before archiving. That's the meaning I derived from the error. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why you want to remove the `sh` file before archiving? It doesnt related to the error, more likely your `sh` file doesnt strip anything as it should be doing